# Failure to return JSON Object with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, kohana, ajaxcontroltoolkit

(Be aware I am using Kohana 3.1.0, so the framework is automatically routing all the following urls)

I'm using the following (jQuery) to request a JSON object from index.php/functions/submit

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submit_enemy").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var query = $(this).serialize();
                $.getJSON('http://arflux-rpg.com/game/index.php/functions/submit', query, function(data){
                    if (data.success == true)
                    {
                        $('#messages').HTML("<div style='color: #00CE06;'>Success. Enemy \'" + data.name + "\' created.</div>");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $('#messages').HTML("<div style='color: #f00;'>Error: " + data.err + "</div>");
                    }
                });
                $('#messages').show(500).fadeOut(1000);
                $('#form_content').show(500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

When the URL is routed, it leads to the following PHP code:
http://pastie.org/2104063

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Any error message? Somewhere? Have you tried it with a relative URL only?

Comment: Can you describe what's happening?

Comment: The Response would be nice to see

Comment: That's the thing, there is no response. Also, I have tried with a relative URL, with the same result.

Comment: Is the request really sent? Does it timeout? Or what is the HTTP response code?

Comment: How would I check? I'm not quite sure how to check for an HTTP response code, but it doesn't timeout.

Comment: You can test it manually from browser, like this - http://arflux-rpg.com/game/index.php/functions/submit?name=test&manliness=123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your backend can't find the proper view to render:

```
throw new Kohana_View_Exception('The requested view :file could not be found', array( //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

You've extended the template controller (`Controller_Template`) which is throwing an exception because it can't find the view file named 'template' (the default).
(I visited the json URL in a browser to see this)

Switching to just extending `Controller` should fix it.

Comment: Or set `auto_render` property to FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Within the action_submit function, you'll have to set `$this->auto_render = false;`

Instead of echoing out the resulting json object, you can use the response object: `$this->response->body(json_encode($return));`